# What's the smallest known interval containing at least one prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

Wikipedia says that Dusart proved in 2010 that there's at least one prime between $x$ and $\left(1 + \frac{1}{25\ln^2x}\right)x$ for $x \geq 396738$. For $x_0 = 396738$, this implies a prime between $x_0$ and $x_0+96$.

My question is: Is Dusart's *the smallest* known interval with at least one prime? Or maybe someone obtained better results?

Comment: You need to elaborate. The gap between $2$ and $3$ *is* the smallest gap between primes. I'm guessing you meant smallest asymptotic gap between primes?

Comment: You mean the asymtotically smallest function $f$ such that there is at least one prime between $x$ and $x+f(x)$ for all (or all sufficiently large) $x$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I didn't notice my mistake. I mean asymptotic gap.

Comment: @hetajr: Can you put the link to Wikipedia? Is it [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function)?

Comment: Here you are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate, see section: better results.

Comment: @hetajr: +1. And I added some details. I hope it's ok.  :)

Comment: OK, I think now everything's more clear ;D

Comment: @hetajr: I didn't expect the interval to be that small at all. I'm more familiar with Bertrand's $n <\text{prime}<2n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a better result ***below a bound*** (see Winther's comment) known since 2003. See "*[Short effective intervals containing primes](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/Maths/gap.pdf)*" by Ramaré and Saouter. In page 13,

**Theorem 3**: *"Let $x>10726905041$. Then the interval,
$$\Big]x\big(1-\tfrac{1}{28314000}\big),\;x\Big]$$
contains at least one prime."*

For example, if we plug in $x_0 = 10726905042$, Theorem 3 states that there is at least one prime between,

$$x_0-378.8\quad \text{and}\quad x_0\tag1$$

However, if we use Dusart's 2010 result, then the interval is,

$$x_0\quad \text{and}\quad x_0+804377.8\tag2$$

So within that bound, Ramaré and Saouter's theorem give a much *shorter* interval than Dusart's.

(*Edit*: Note that the gap between the two consecutive primes, 
$$p_2-p_1 = 10726905041-10726904659 = 382 > 378.8$$ 
and is #36 of [the first 75 maximal gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results). Thus, a reason why $x > p_2$.)

Comment: Great! That's what I've been looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: So Dusart didn't know about this result? Dusart's paper is from 2010, this one from 2002...

Comment: @hetajr: If it was his thesis, he must have known.

Comment: I don't really see in which sense this result is stronger than Dusart's. This one gives an interval of length $\mathrm{const}\cdot x$, while Dusart's result gives length $o(x)$...

Comment: To be precise, the quoted result is only better for $x \lesssim 10^{462}$. For larger $x$ Dusart's result is better.

Comment: I was hoping someone would point that out.

Comment: @Winther: It did occur to me that Dusart's result might eventually overtake Theorem 3. Serves me right for not exploring the implications thoroughly.  :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Dear Tito: Is the Theorem 3 you mentioned related to the Rieman hypothesis. The same question is for the Dusart boundes described in the question.

Comment: @Winther: Is the Theorem 3 you mentioned related to the Rieman hypothesis. The same question is for the Dusart boundes described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically, Baker-Harman-Pintz is the best known result: for sufficiently large $x$ there is always a prime in the interval $[x,x+x^{0.525}]$, but I'm not sure that anyone's worked out an explicit value for "sufficiently large".  [This paper of Dudek](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4233) gives an explicit estimate for $[x^3, (x+1)^3]$, which is again asymptotically much better than $cx$ or $x/\log^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

The best unconditionally known result is the one listed below Dusart's on the page you linked to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results):  Baker, Harman, and Pintz proved in 2001 ([link to paper](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/83/3/532.full.pdf+html)) that there is always a prime in the interval $[x - x^{0.525}, x]$ for $x$ sufficiently large.  (They don't specify how large is sufficiently large, but assert that this could be determined "with enough effort".)  For reasonably large $x$, this $x^{0.525}$ gap is much smaller than either $x/28314000$ or $x/(25 \ln^2 x)$.

Additionally, Harald Cramér proved conditionally on the Riemann hypothesis that the $x^{0.525}$ can be reduced to $O(\sqrt x \ln x)$, and he conjectured (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture) that it can be reduced even to $O(\ln^2 x)$.  This seems very far beyond what we could hope to prove in the near future, but it's the strongest bound that looks likely to be true.