# Examples of intervals that contain at least one prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

So far, I've gathered these intervals that contain at least one prime but are there other important results that I might have overlooked?

**1. [Oppermann's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture)**: $[x^2,x^2+x]$

**2. [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)**: $[x,2x]$

**3. [Fourier optimization and prime gaps](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04122)**: $[x, x + \frac{22}{25}\sqrt{x} \log(x)]$

**4. [Riemann Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis)**: $[x, x + x^{1/2 + \epsilon}]$

**5. [Baker, Harman, and Pintz](https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/83/3/532/1479119)**: $[x,x+x^{0.525}]$

**6. [Cramér's conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958053/the-conjecture-that-there-is-always-a-prime-between-n-and-nc-log2n)**: $[x, x + C \log^2(x)]$

**7. [Dudek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4233)**: $[x^3,(x+1)^3]$

**8. [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture)**: $[x^2,(x+1)^2]$

**9. [Dusart](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413701/whats-the-smallest-known-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number)**: $[\left(1 + \frac{1}{25\ln^2x}\right)x,x]$

**10. [Short effective intervals containing primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413701/whats-the-smallest-known-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number)**: $]x\big(1-\tfrac{1}{28314000}\big),\;x]$

Comment: It's important to note that not all of these are proved! #1,3,6,8 are open problems (and #4 is a conditional result on RH).

Comment: And they hold only for sufficiently large $x$, which is known in some cases explicitly. For 10., it is $>10726905041$. For 7. it is $x≥\exp(\exp(33.217)) $ and so on.

Comment: in 6. numerical evidence suggests $C=1$   works for $x  \geq 8$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results

Comment: in the small table of large "merit," the condition $C \leq 1$ is confirmed for those numbers $(M,g)$ when $M^2 < g,$   because $M = \frac{g}{\log p}$

Comment: Could you please add a link to each example (wikipedia or wolfram).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more.

The Firoozbakht conjecture is equivalent to the statement that there is a prime in the interval

$$
[x,x + \ln^2x - \ln x + 1]
$$

This is stronger than the Cramer-Granville heuristics and the conjecture is believed to the false but has not been disproved.